# Set max value of three input numbers together

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, numbers

I have three input numbers:

```html
<input min="0" name="cat1" step="1" type="number" max="50" value="0" />            
<input min="0" name="cat2" step="1" type="number" max="50" value="0" />
<input min="0" name="cat3" step="1" type="number" max="50" value="0" />
```

Currently the max value is 50. I would like the max for all three together to be 50 aswell.

How can I solve this with javascript or jquery?

Comment: `I would like the max for all three together to be 50 aswell` what?

Comment: I believe the TS means that the **sum** of all three together shouldn't be more than 50 as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This method sums the other inputs, and if the sum + the current value is greater than max, it changes the current input's value to fit max.

For example, try entering 30, 5, 20 to the input boxes.

```js
var max = 50;
var $inputs = $('input');

function sumInputs($inputs) {
  var sum = 0;
  
  $inputs.each(function() {
    sum += parseInt($(this).val(), 0);
  });

  return sum;
}

$inputs.on('input', function(e) {
  var $this = $(this);
  var sum = sumInputs($inputs.not(function(i, el) {
    return el === e.target;
  }));
  var value = parseInt($this.val(), 10) || 0;
  if(sum + value > max) $this.val(max - sum);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input min="0" name="cat1" step="1" type="number" max="50" value="0" />
<input min="0" name="cat2" step="1" type="number" max="50" value="0" />
<input min="0" name="cat3" step="1" type="number" max="50" value="0" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope you expected this way.
**Try Using this code.**
it will check the aggregate of three fields and check it whether it is greater than 50.

```js
$(":input").bind('keyup mouseup', function () {          

  var cat1=$("#cat1").val();
  var cat2=$("#cat2").val();
  var cat3=$("#cat3").val();
  var total=parseInt(cat1) + parseInt(cat2) + parseInt(cat3);
 
  if(total>50) {
    alert("it exceeds 50");
    return false;
  }
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input min="0" id="cat1"  name="cat1" step="1" type="number" max="50" value="0" />            
<input min="0" id="cat2"  name="cat2" step="1" type="number" max="50" value="0" />
<input min="0" id="cat3"  name="cat3" step="1" type="number" max="50" value="0" />
```

Answer (score 1):

This will ensure the sum doesn't exceed 50. In case the new value makes the total exceed the limit, the other two will be lowered equally to enforce the total=50 rule.

Note the

```
let share2 = Math.min(Math.floor(excessValue / 2), elmt2Value) which ensures
```

To ensure we won't remove more from one of the input than its value.

```
<input min="0" name="cat1" id="cat1" step="1" type="number" max="50" value="0" onchange="valueChanged('cat1')" />            
<input min="0" name="cat2" id="cat2" step="1" type="number" max="50" value="0" onchange="valueChanged('cat2')" />
<input min="0" name="cat3" id="cat3" step="1" type="number" max="50" value="0" onchange="valueChanged('cat3')" />

<script>
     function valueChanged(changedElmtId) {

        // Retrieve all input, the one changed and the other 2
        let elmt2Id = "cat2", elmt3Id = "cat3"
        if ( changedElmtId === elmt2Id ) {
            elmt2Id = "cat1"
        }
        else if ( changedElmtId === elmt3Id ) {
            elmt3Id = "cat1"
        }

        let changedElmt = document.querySelector("#" + changedElmtId)
        let elmt2 = document.querySelector("#" + elmt2Id)
        let elmt3 = document.querySelector("#" + elmt3Id)

        let elmt2Value = parseInt(elmt2.value)
        let elmt3Value = parseInt(elmt3.value)

        // Check if any action is needed
        let totalValue = parseInt(changedElmt.value) + elmt2Value + elmt3Value
        if ( isNaN(totalValue) || totalValue <= 50 )
            return

        // Measure excess then split in 2
        let excessValue = totalValue - 50
        let share2 = Math.min(Math.floor(excessValue / 2), elmt2Value)
        let share3 = excessValue - share2

        console.log("Current:", " " + elmt2Id + ": ", share2, " " + elmt3Id + ": ", share3)
        console.log("Total:", totalValue, " Excess: ", excessValue, " " + elmt2Id + ": ", share2, " " + elmt3Id + ": ", share3)


        elmt2.value = elmt2Value - share2
        elmt3.value = elmt3Value - share3

     }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how optimal my solution is but it works. Covered some edge cases too.

```js
let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');
const max = inputs[0].getAttribute("max");
let value;
inputs.forEach((input, i) => {
  input.addEventListener('change',(e) =>handleChange(e)); // adding change event
  input.addEventListener('blur',(e) =>handleChange(e)); //adding a blur eventto prevent direct  typing of input larger than max
})

const handleChange = (e) =>{  
  if(e.target.value > max - value){
    e.target.value = max-value; //setting max value possible if input value is greater than max
    return;
  }else{
    value = 0;
    inputs.forEach( input => {
      value+=parseInt(input.value); //calculating value to negate from max
    });
    inputs.forEach( input => {
      if(max-value > 0){
       input.setAttribute("max", max-value);  //setting max value on every input
      }    
    }); 
  }     
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <input min="0" name="cat1" step="1" type="number" max="50" value="0" />            
  <input min="0" name="cat2" step="1" type="number" max="50" value="0" />
  <input min="0" name="cat3" step="1" type="number" max="50" value="0" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope that works for you easy small and fast for lesser number of input in form.

```js
$(function(){
  $('input[type=number]').attr('max', '50')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input min="0" name="cat1" step="1" type="number" value="0" />
<input min="0" name="cat2" step="1" type="number" value="0" />
<input min="0" name="cat3" step="1" type="number" value="0" />
```