# I add the max value of three input numbers and it's worked but how to add the increment decrement button without losing the max value?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I need the addition of a three-element is 8, with click + and - button. But, I don't want that it will increase each element up to 8.

```js
// Addtion of select items LINK - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49644837/set-max-value-of-three-input-numbers-together
var max = 8;
var $inputs = $('input');

function sumInputs($inputs) {
    var sum = 0;

    $inputs.each(function() {
        sum += parseInt($(this).val(), 0);
    });

    return sum;
}

$inputs.on('input', function(e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    var sum = sumInputs($inputs.not(function(i, el) {
        return el === e.target;
    }));
    var value = parseInt($this.val(), 10) || 0;
    if (sum + value > max) $this.val(max - sum);
});


//Increment Decrement value

function up(max) {
    document.getElementById("myNumber").value = parseInt(document.getElementById("myNumber").value) + 1;

    if (document.getElementById("myNumber").value >= parseInt(max)) {
        document.getElementById("myNumber").value = max;

    }
}

function down(min) {
    document.getElementById("myNumber").value = parseInt(document.getElementById("myNumber").value) - 1;
    if (document.getElementById("myNumber").value <= parseInt(min)) {
        document.getElementById("myNumber").value = min;
    }
}


function up2(max) {
    document.getElementById("myNumber2").value = parseInt(document.getElementById("myNumber2").value) + 1;
    if (document.getElementById("myNumber2").value >= parseInt(max)) {
        document.getElementById("myNumber2").value = max;
    }
}

function down2(min) {
    document.getElementById("myNumber2").value = parseInt(document.getElementById("myNumber2").value) - 1;
    if (document.getElementById("myNumber2").value <= parseInt(min)) {
        document.getElementById("myNumber2").value = min;
    }
}


function up3(max) {
    document.getElementById("myNumber3").value = parseInt(document.getElementById("myNumber3").value) + 1;
    if (document.getElementById("myNumber3").value >= parseInt(max)) {
        document.getElementById("myNumber3").value = max;
    }
}

function down3(min) {
    document.getElementById("myNumber3").value = parseInt(document.getElementById("myNumber3").value) - 1;
    if (document.getElementById("myNumber3").value <= parseInt(min)) {
        document.getElementById("myNumber3").value = min;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="select-1">
    <button type="submit" value="-" onclick=" down('0')" class="sub" id="">-</button>
    <input type="number" id="myNumber" value="0" name="qty" max="8" min="0" step="1"/>
    <button type="submit" value="+" onclick="up('8')" class="add">+</button>
</div>
<div class="select-2">
    <button type="submit" value="-" onclick=" down2('0')" class="sub">-</button>
    <input type="number" id="myNumber2" value="0" name="qty2" max="8" min="0" step="1"/>
    <button type="submit" value="+" onclick="up2('8')" class="add">+</button>
</div>
<div class="select-3">
    <button type="submit" value="-" onclick=" down3('0')" class="sub" id="">-</button>
    <input type="number" id="myNumber3" value="0" name="qty3" max="8" min="0" step="1"/>
    <button type="submit" value="+" onclick="up3('8')" class="add">+</button>
</div>
```

Currently, the max value is 8. I would like to get the max value with the + and - button as well.

How can I solve this with javascript or jquery?

Here, there is a link below I follow for increment and decrement.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49645518/15412266

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        

        <button type="submit" value="+" onclick="minusoperation(1)" class="minus">-</button>
        <input type="number" class="numbers" id="number1" min="0" max="8" onchange="inputNumber(this)" data-prevvalue=0 />
        <button type="submit" value="+" onclick="plusoperation(1)" class="plus">+</button>

        <button type="submit" value="+" onclick="minusoperation(2)" class="minus">-</button>
        <input type="number" class="numbers" id="number2" min="0" max="8" onchange="inputNumber(this)" data-prevvalue=0 />
        <button type="submit" value="+" onclick="plusoperation(2)" class="plus">+</button>


        <button type="submit" value="+" onclick="minusoperation(3)" class="minus">-</button>
        <input type="number" class="numbers" id="number3" min="0" max="8" onchange="inputNumber(this)" data-prevvalue=0 />
        <button type="submit" value="+" onclick="plusoperation(3)" class="plus">+</button>


    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function inputNumber(el)
        {
            
            var myElements = document.getElementsByClassName('numbers');
            var sum = 0;
            for (var i=0;i<myElements.length;i++) {
                if(myElements[i].value)
                    sum = sum+parseInt(myElements[i].value);
            }
            if(sum<=8)
            {
                el.dataset.prevvalue  = el.value;
            } else {
                el.value  = el.dataset.prevvalue;
            }

        }

        function minusoperation(inputNumber)
        {

            var el = document.getElementById('number'+inputNumber);
            if(parseInt(el.value))
            {
                el.value = parseInt(el.value)-1;

            } else {
                el.value = 0;
            }
            el.onchange();
        }

        function plusoperation(inputNumber)
        {
            var el = document.getElementById('number'+inputNumber);

            if(parseInt(el.value))
            {
                el.value = parseInt(el.value)+1;
            } else {
                el.value = 1;
            }
            el.onchange();

        }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, Ankit Singh, but I want to increase and decrease the value by click + and - buttons around them.

Comment: Okay, got it. I have made some changes as per your requirement